# Load product stock quantity by SKU : Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to get product quantity by using SKU. I have this code but give me null:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,

        array $data = []
    )
    {

        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;

    }

public function getProductBySku($sku)
{
  return $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
}



$_product = $this->getProductBySku($itm['sku']);
echo $_product->Qty();
```

Comment: Did you try `$product->getQty()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository as StockItem;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as Product;

protected $stockItem;

protected $product;


public function __construct(
    ...
    StockItem $stockItem,
    Product $product
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
    $this->product = $product;
    ....
}
```

Now you can use like this,

```
$productId=$this->product->getIdBySku('YOUR_SKU');
if($productId){
    $productStock = $this->stockItem->get($productId);
    $productQty = $productStock->getQty();
}
```

---

Using Object Manager (Not recommended)

```
   $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();           
    $productId = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku('YOUR_SKU');
    $stockItem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository');
if($productId){
    $productQty = $stockItem->get($productId)->getQty();
   }
```

Comment: wrong. StockItemRepository accepts parameter item_id not product id.

Answer (score 6):

This is better

```
protected $stockRegistry; 
  public function __construct(

    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
) {

    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;

}



 public function quantity() {
   return this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku)->getQty()
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  As mentioned in the comments above, the answer by Keyur is not pulling via the correct ID.  Additionally - this is the simple/clean method to get the desired infomration.

Comment: Interface \Magento\CatalogInventory\ApiStockRegistryInterface is deprecated, should not be used . Check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/inventory/inventory-api-reference.html